# How do I add an SVG g element from a template?

Tags: javascript, html, templates, svg

I am trying to add an SVG g element to an SVG tag using JavaScript. The g element is defined in a template tag. It is in a template tag as I want to reuse it many times.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Template Example</title>
        <style media="screen">
            svg {
                margin: auto;
            }
            g {
                stroke:black;
                stroke-width:2px;
                fill:none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <template>
            <g>
               <line x1=" 2" y1="2" x2=" 7" y2="7" ></line>
               <line x1="25" y1="2" x2="20" y2="7" ></line>
               <path class="botLeft" d="m 1,26 6,-6" ></path>
               <path class="botRite" d="m 26,26 -6,-6" ></path>
               <rect x="1" y="1" rx="3" ry="3" width="25" height="25" ></rect>
               <path class="rectIn" d="m 7,7 0,13 13,0 0,-13 z" style="fill:gray;" ></path>
            </g>
        </template>

        <svg width="80%" height="80%" ></svg>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var temp = document.getElementsByTagName("template")[0];
            var clon = temp.content.cloneNode(true);
            var svg = document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0];
            svg.appendChild(clon);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This code adds the g element to the DOM in the correct place, but the element is not rendered.

After reading other posts regarding SVG, I think this is because this is not a normal HTML element, but an SVG Element.

How do I advise the browser to treat this as an SVG element?

I have seen some remarks hinting at namespaces but can not understand what is needed.

Any pointers will be appreciated ;-)

Answer (score 4):

If you put the elements in the SVG itself and embed them with a `<defs>` tag instead of a `<template>` tag they will all get created in the right namespace and also be invisible.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Template Example</title>
        <style media="screen">
            svg {
                margin: auto;
            }
            g {
                stroke:black;
                stroke-width:2px;
                fill:none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <svg width="80%" height="80%" >
            <defs>
            <g>
               <line x1=" 2" y1="2" x2=" 7" y2="7" ></line>
               <line x1="25" y1="2" x2="20" y2="7" ></line>
               <path class="botLeft" d="m 1,26 6,-6" ></path>
               <path class="botRite" d="m 26,26 -6,-6" ></path>
               <rect x="1" y="1" rx="3" ry="3" width="25" height="25" ></rect>
               <path class="rectIn" d="m 7,7 0,13 13,0 0,-13 z" style="fill:gray;" ></path>
            </g>
            </defs>        
        </svg>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var temp = document.getElementsByTagName("g")[0];
            var clon = temp.cloneNode(true);
            var svg = document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0];
            svg.appendChild(clon);
            var clon2 = temp.cloneNode(true);
            clon2.setAttribute("transform", "translate(50,0)");
            svg.appendChild(clon2);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think this will help him, you no longer have a template that can be reused as he stated in his question 'It is in a template tag as I want to reuse it many times'. I have used your code and added a few svg element to try and reuse your code and as you can see it fails: https://codepen.io/mrdeadsven/pen/RJppwY. If I'm correct he wants something similar to my previous answer i gave: https://codepen.io/mrdeadsven/pen/MXyrPM?editors=1010. As you can see he can reuse this as much as he wants. Also I don't get your first sentence 'embed them with a TAG instead of aTAG'.

Comment: @mrdeadsven Sure I do, all I've done is use the word <defs> instead of the word <template>.  You have a different bug in your examples. I could correct your misunderstanding of how appendChild works if you asked a question about it. I've fixed the formatting of the sentence that was missing words.

Comment: I don't have questions about appendChild, don't worry. But maybe you could adjust your answer, so it has multiple svg elements (as in my snippets) and then use your variable clon on the new svg's so your code snippets shows that it is reusable as asked in the question. If you do so I will up vote your answer. It would be correcter to OP as my answer, because he won't need any extra libraries.

Comment: @mrdeadsven sure if you want, perhaps if you look at it you'll realise what you're doing wrong.

Comment: @Robert Longson - If I understand correctly you are using the SVG tag as the template by defining the g element inside the defs tag. Intresting and helpful approach. Thank you ;-)

Comment: Ok, seems I misunderstood OP's question. Because all you did is create a new variable clon2 (which in my opinion is not reusable code as I don't want to create 50 more clons, I would just want to reuse the one existing). And also I thought it needed to be reusable in multiple svg elements and not just create new ones to just translate them in the current svg element. So guess I misunderstood the question? Also this only works if <defs> is embedded in the svg, do you also have an approach that works without everything in the svg like in the question? @RobertLongson

Comment: @mrdeadsven If I don't translate it it will draw on top of the other one and you'll just tell me it didn't work because you can only see one shape. You can create whatever you want. If you want to reuse the clon variable you can do that. You can put the <defs> in another <svg> if you want.

Comment: @RobertLongson I think your missing the point of my question. Your answer only works in a very specific case and as I stated before is not reusable. reusable means that I can create a new svg in the html and use the function to just fill the svg with the template. reusable does not mean create a new svg element with AGAIN all of your code of <defs><g> etc. If i use your code to add 20svg elements I will have 220lines of code while if it was really reusable it would be 20.

Comment: @mrdeadsven You'd use a loop. I'm not going to discuss this further in comments. If you have a question, ask it separately.

Comment: Did you actually try it?  Robert's approach works perfectly fine if you update the code to clone to other SVGs. You can clone the `<g>`, from any SVG, and append it to any other SVG.  Whether it is in a `<defs>` or not.  It is only in a `<defs>` here so that it does not get rendered until it is cloned.  [See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/se3aghbv/8/)

Comment: @PaulLeBeau Clean code and now perfectly understandable. If this was the code in the snippet I would have immediately agreed to it. However from the above snippet and the explanation I was given I wouldn't have come to this conclusion. And Yes I was actually trying to accomplish what you did with his code, but I must admit I failed at it. And that is why I was being persistent in the comment, because I always try to give an easy and useful answer that meets all the requirements of the question in the answer.

Comment: @mrdeadsven To be fair to Robert, your question doesn't make it clear that you want to clone to multiple different SVGs. You just say"add a g to a svg".

Comment: @paullebeau it’s not actually his question at all.

Comment: The initial question was: "How do I add an SVG **g** element from a template?". I am here because my own question was a bit more general: "How do I add an SVG element from a template?". And your overall answer answers perfectly my question. I can understand now that <defs> acts as a <template> within the SVG namespace. What has been added is that svg-fragments can come from n SVG's and be inserted into m SVG"s. And this is perfect, with pure JS HTML API's. Thank you (I am not supposed to say that) @RobertLongson